# Intercept video frames in a WebRTC session for effects processing?

Tags: c#, video, html5-video, webrtc, cefsharp

I have a C#/C++ app that captures a video stream from the camera connected to a user's PC. It then does user segmentation using the Intel RealSense SDK to automatically remove the background from the user. What I need to know is how to 
insert myself into the video delivery chain so I get each frame, process it, and send it on to the WebRTC module.

The whole desired effect is to make the user look like they are superimposed over the web page. Note, the only browser I need to support is Chrome since I am running the Chromium DLLs in an embedded browser, thanks to the CefSharp project.

The one piece I can't figure out is to put myself into the video so I can get notified when a new video frame is available, modify it, and then pass it on to WebRTC in Chromium.  I downloaded the Chromium source and can't find the keyword getUserMedia anywhere.

Comment: Try online search: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#search/&q=getUserMedia%20-test&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a port of Chromium, this means that you should have access to WebGL calls through WebKit.

Instead of doing it on the app-side, try doing it on your HTML.

Since the question is "Intercept video frames in a WebRTC session for effects processing?" I think this post and the demo it has, which is on github, does exactly what you are asking for:

[Using WebGL to apply effects to WebRTC video frames](http://www.agilityfeat.com/blog/2015/08/did-you-know-using-webgl-shaders-on-webrtc-video)

And since WebGL shaders are basically written in C++ (GLSL), you could easily create a fragment/pixel shader which removes the background. Odds are that there's probably already one out there, it'd be worth trying to google for that one.

Also, in case performance concerns you, doing it this way would be just as fast since shaders work off of the GPU; even in mobile.